# Hover effect over image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to apply a hover effect to the images in my WP theme. It is a grid of images created by the featured image on the posts.

the grid is controlled in content.php

```
<?php
/**
 * controls main grid images
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-md-4 col-sm-4 pbox '); ?>>

    <div class = "box-ovrly">
      <h2 class="box-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <div class="box-meta"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
    </div>

    <?php
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
        $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 750, 560, true ); //resize & crop the image
    ?>

    <?php if($image) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <img class="img-responsive hover-decal" src="<?php echo $image ?>"/></a>
    <?php endif; ?> 

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

I want to turn 'box-overly' div into the overlay on top of the image but can't find the proper js and css.

the css I have right now ...

```
.box-ovrly {
z-index: 100;
position: absolute;
top: 0px
left: 0px;
}
```

It puts the title and category on top of the image. I want it to have a background to cover the image on hover, but not to show up at all until hovered over

the perfect example of what i'm looking to do (eventually different background colours, etc. But I don't want any text on the image until hovered) for is on this portfolio

http://redantler.com/work/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that effect with pure CSS.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/y3z4pojv/6/

In the code below, the most important part is the `.element:hover > .elementHover` bit. This means "display `.elementHover`, which is the child of `.element`, WHEN `.element` is being hovered".

Just check out how the HTML is structured in this example, and emulate that in your WordPress code. (With the appropriate names for your elements, of course).

**Test CSS:**

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.strawberries {
    background: url('http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/16300000/Delicious-pretty-fruit-fruit-16382128-670-562.jpg');
}
.watermelon {
    background: url('http://fyi.uwex.edu/safepreserving/files/2013/08/watermelon.jpg');
}
.pineapple {
    background: url('http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/7/71129/2672509-6564604021-pinea.jpg');
}
.element:hover > .elementHover {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}
.elementHover {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms;
}
.hoverContent {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 200%;
    padding: 1em;
}
.hoverBackground {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.green {
    background: green;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

**Test HTML:**

```
<div class="element strawberries">
    <div class="elementHover">
        <img class="hoverBackground" src="http://www.aux.tv/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/how-to-rick-roll-somebody.jpg"/>
        <span class="hoverContent">
            Hello there
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="element watermelon">
    <div class="elementHover">
        <div class="hoverBackground green"></div>
        <span class="hoverContent">
            Goodbye now
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="element pineapple">
    <div class="elementHover">
        <div class="hoverBackground red"></div>
        <span class="hoverContent">
            ...Not yet
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that you can just have a plain colored `DIV` instead of an `IMG` on hover, all you need to do is change the `IMG`  tag to `DIV` and set a background to `.hoverBackground`.

Comment: That seems to work good in the example and is fairly simple. But As I mentioned that once I get it wiring I want to next change the hover background to different colours for different posts. I assume this involved js, so will this technique integrate well with that?

Comment: Yeah, sure, you just need to add more classes, and specify the style you want for each different post. I'll update the jsFiddle in a bit.

Comment: Take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/y3z4pojv/5/
Is this what you want? You can pretty much style them in any way you want. Just keep on adding classes.

Comment: When I apply it to my wordpress (I copied your css and changed the markup of 'box-ovrly' to the example you provided it breaks the grid and the 'overlay' appears outside the image. The other issue is that this is a post loop so the posts are created with the loop so I cannot hard code each one independently

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to tell what it could be without looking at how your grid is styled, but you can try setting `top: 0; left: 0` to `.hoverBackground` AND `position: absolute` to `.hoverContent`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y3z4pojv/8/ I made such changes in there. Also, make sure that `.element` has `overflow: hidden` set.

Comment: well you've given me a good start, thank you. My theme is a child of Wembly from Fab themes

Answer (score 0):

Had to do something similar, but hopefully this works for you. Of course, modify for your usage. This is a simplistic version

Ver. 1 (html, JS and CSS in the link, JS posted here):
http://jsfiddle.net/SnvMr/6/

```
$('.effect').hover(
    function() {
        $('.effect').not(this).stop().fadeTo(500, 0.33);
        $(this).find('p').fadeIn(500);
    }, function() {
        $('.effect').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
        $('.effect p').fadeOut(500);
    }
);
```

Ver. 2:
http://jsfiddle.net/deelite/SnvMr/12/

Comment: can i add this directly into functions.php or do I need to bring it in through external js. Version 2 looks like it works better

Comment: Just add it to your JS file and your Style file. modify to your liking. I know the code i gave has text overlay as well (and a fade effect when hover over one of the elements on the other elements) but just remove those details from the HTML/JS/CSS.

You can call it Via your function or your code, you call what ever style class or id you want it to affect. 

The JS is just to have a smooth transition between the images you are using, in this case fading.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work in my file, I have created a new js/hover-decal.js and used your coding from the jsfiddle

Comment: Are you calling the correct jquery version? also a link to your work will help.

Comment: the theme calls for the most up-to-date query. Unfortunately my work is still on localhost so I can't provide it online